# Will arbitrary folders save after reinstalling Windows?

Tags: windows-8, windows.old

I need to reinstall Windows 8 but want to keep an important folder, `C:\Data`. What folders are saved in `_windows.old_`? Are manually created folders in the root of the hard disk copied?

At the moment, there is no possibility to copy these files manually.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. Feel free to edit the post.

Comment: Are you reformatting or are you doing an upgrade?

Comment: @root - reformatting.

Comment: "These files must not be lost! " Then back them up to another drive!

Comment: Since you don't have access to another hard disk, I'd suggest backing up the important files to Dropbox, Google Drive or any other cloud storage provider before you proceed with the re-installation.

Comment: Files located outside of your profile folder won't be saved.

Comment: @Ramhound - This is exactly what I wanted to know. Write it down as an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - The current answer to this question already states that.  Besides this question has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Windows.old` folder is only created when doing a [Windows upgrade](http://www.howtogeek.com/223821/what-is-the-windows.old-folder-and-how-do-you-delete-it/) or if you install Windows on top of an existing installation. When reformatting, you are essentially deleting everything from your drive, then reinstalling the operating system - thus keeping nothing from the original installation.

After an upgrade, the `Windows.old` will contain files and folders found from your user profile, and do not include folders you've created in `C:\`.

Comment: "The Windows.old folder is only created when doing a Windows upgrade." - This is partial false.  It also is created if you install Windows ontop of an existing installation.  The reason I say only partially false is because that is what initially happens doing an upgrade installation.